# how to make IBM bucket public to use it for static website

Tags: amazon-s3, ibm-cloud

I am using Amazoon S3 SDK to perform operations on buckets to use it for static website,
but it always create the bucket to private.

```
            PutACLRequest req = new PutACLRequest()
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
               CannedACL= S3CannedACL.PublicRead
            };
```

Comment: What is the context, what SDK and programming language? Have you tested it in the IBM Cloud console for COS?

Comment: I am using .net SDK with C# to create the bucket which works fine, but it stays private, and i want to make it public. which i tried to do with above code, that doesn't work.

Comment: Is there an IBM .NET SDK for COS? Please provide a link and add details to your question. Have you tested it like this, just for proof? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-iam-public-access#public-access-object

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/coss/3.15.2?topic=development-configure-net-sdk

Comment: Please edit your question with more context.